# Form displayed as code file after duplicate with copy / paste

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have tried to copy and paste a C# form in VS 2017 which I need including the code, but after renaming the form in Visual Studio, it is displayed only as C# code instead of form. It compiles without any error, but I cannot edit the form.

[image]

I have tried to copy-paste-rename in the explorer all the 3 files and then include them in the project with "show all files" and it ads the form to the project  only as c# code file instead of form

Comment: Instead of copy / paste, use **Add Existing Item** and add the `form.cs` and `form.designer.cs` and `form.resx`

Comment: I does the same, it ads the files as c# code instead of form

Comment: Copy/Paste from the solution explorer will add all files required (code, designer and eventually the resources) adding the - Copy string to the new files. This is the correct behavior and if you don't have then there is a different problem at play here. Then you could rename the main file to the name you like and this will rename also the dependent files. After that remember that you now have two form classes with the same name. You need to open the main file and the designer and change the name of the class. After that remember to close everything and then you can try to reopen the form file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand it create a new project and normally add Form1 and Form2. Then copy paste another form (we name it form3) .cs, .designer.cs and .resx files to the project. Now go to your project in windows explorer and open your PROJECT.csproj file in a text editor. you will see:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form2.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form2.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form2.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form3.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form3.Designer.cs" />
```

As you see we don't have any dependency for `Form3.Designer.cs` to Form3.

And we have also:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form2.resx">
  <DependentUpon>Form2.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

That depend the .resx file to their form but we have not it for Form3.

To have a normal Form3 you must change it to get exactly like Form1 and Form2.
But as quetzalcoatl Said it is better to create new form and copy/paste only the content of the form you want.

**Update**:

As an easy way you can Firstly create Form3 (the copy/paste form) in your project normally by:

> Add -> New Item

Now you have all you need in .csproj file and it doesn't need to edit. Then copy/replace the 3 files .cs .designer.cs and .resx in **windows explorer** to your project.

Comment: I can't paste only the content because there are many controls in the form with events. If I paste only the contents I will lose all the events.

Comment: changing the csproj file displays the file as a form in visual studio for a few seconds then it turns back to code only. If I click on the form quickly after project load then I get this error: The class FormLearnFromHistoryAI can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.

Comment: No you will not lose your events. Events are saved in .designer file, and you must copy/paste both form.cs and form.designer.cs

Comment: Please check you .csproj file again. and for the new form you must have exactly what other forms have. not any thing more and not less. And the problem would be solved I tested just now.

Comment: Yes it works now, I had a class before the Form class in the same file.

Comment: I have completely removed all other classes from the form file and after the first edit of the form in VS it changes back to code file only. I have to add it back to csproj after every edit.